# jQuery UI datepicker: onSelect called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, enter

I noticed a strange behavior with the jQuery datepicker onSelect method, you can take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8Pvp/3/) to test it.

Tested with jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.18, happens in Firefox, IE and Chrome.

Scenario:

1. put the focus on the text field (the datepicker should appear)
2. press enter to select the default date (as [the datepicker API](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) says it can be done)
3. notice that onSelect is called twice.

Everything works fine if you select the date with the mouse.

Is this a bug? If not, how can I avoid this behaviour? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am on mac osx safari `Version 5.1.6 ` only one select ? hmmm

Comment: Yes, it is happening in my firefox 11.0. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, even I got this error some time back but just neglected it. 
But this time i looked into the datepicker script where I found as it might be bug. This is reproducible in specific way only as you have mentioned

- Click on the field/ bring focus on it by using tab
- press enter

You will have callback function 'onSelect' called twice.

This is because in datepicker javascript, '_selectDate' function is used to get the selected date which is called from key event handler function(_doKeyDown()->_selectDay()->_selectDate()) and both functions
invokes the call back function which seems to be bug.

---

Updates -

I have modified the _doKeyDown function in jquery.ui.datepicker.js file. I have modified the code when event is enter(keycode-13). **So now callback function 'onSelect' is called once in above scenario.**

Here is the code for version 1.8.21

```
_doKeyDown: function(event) {
        var inst = $.datepicker._getInst(event.target);
        var handled = true;
        var isRTL = inst.dpDiv.is('.ui-datepicker-rtl');
        inst._keyEvent = true;
        if ($.datepicker._datepickerShowing)
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 9: $.datepicker._hideDatepicker();
                        handled = false;
                        break; // hide on tab out
                case 13: var sel = $('td.' + $.datepicker._dayOverClass + ':not(.' + 
                                    $.datepicker._currentClass + ')', inst.dpDiv);
                        //Update by Sunil start
                        if (sel[0]){
                            $.datepicker._selectDay(event.target, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedYear, sel[0]);
                        }else{
                            $.datepicker._hideDatepicker();
                            return true;
                        }
                        //Update by Sunil end
                        return false;
                        break; // select the value on enter
                case 27: $.datepicker._hideDatepicker();
                        break; // hide on escape
                case 33: $.datepicker._adjustDate(event.target, (event.ctrlKey ?
                            -$.datepicker._get(inst, 'stepBigMonths') :
                            -$.datepicker._get(inst, 'stepMonths')), 'M');
                        break; // previous month/year on page up/+ ctrl
                case 34: $.datepicker._adjustDate(event.target, (event.ctrlKey ?
                            +$.datepicker._get(inst, 'stepBigMonths') :
                            +$.datepicker._get(inst, 'stepMonths')), 'M');
                        break; // next month/year on page down/+ ctrl
                case 35: if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) $.datepicker._clearDate(event.target);
                        handled = event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey;
                        break; // clear on ctrl or command +end
                case 36: if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) $.datepicker._gotoToday(event.target);
                        handled = event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey;
                        break; // current on ctrl or command +home
                case 37: if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) $.datepicker._adjustDate(event.target, (isRTL ? +1 : -1), 'D');
                        handled = event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey;
                        // -1 day on ctrl or command +left
                        if (event.originalEvent.altKey) $.datepicker._adjustDate(event.target, (event.ctrlKey ?
                                    -$.datepicker._get(inst, 'stepBigMonths') :
                                    -$.datepicker._get(inst, 'stepMonths')), 'M');
                        // next month/year on alt +left on Mac
                        break;
                case 38: if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) $.datepicker._adjustDate(event.target, -7, 'D');
                        handled = event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey;
                        break; // -1 week on ctrl or command +up
                case 39: if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) $.datepicker._adjustDate(event.target, (isRTL ? -1 : +1), 'D');
                        handled = event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey;
                        // +1 day on ctrl or command +right
                        if (event.originalEvent.altKey) $.datepicker._adjustDate(event.target, (event.ctrlKey ?
                                    +$.datepicker._get(inst, 'stepBigMonths') :
                                    +$.datepicker._get(inst, 'stepMonths')), 'M');
                        // next month/year on alt +right
                        break;
                case 40: if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) $.datepicker._adjustDate(event.target, +7, 'D');
                        handled = event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey;
                        break; // +1 week on ctrl or command +down
                default: handled = false;
            }
        else if (event.keyCode == 36 && event.ctrlKey) // display the date picker on ctrl+home
            $.datepicker._showDatepicker(this);
        else {
            handled = false;
        }
        if (handled) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    },
```

I hope this would fix your problem.

---

Update 2 
There is another workaround as answered by user1042031 but not complete solution. Here you will find what you need to do

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
     onSelect: function(dateText,inst) {       
         $.datepicker._hideDatepicker();
         inst.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You need to remove alert which causes to set focus on input field which will show datepicker again. This is call onSelect once for sure hiding the datepicker after pressing enter key.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/chavansi/hAkhY/)

I am copying the part of solution just to have both working ways :)

Comment: Nice work, but I'd rather not modify the source code; I don't want this issue to reappear if anyone changes/upgrades the datepicker file. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution suggestion that is so ugly I'm half ashamed to post it. However, desparate times call for desperate measures.

```
var trigger = false;
var previousDate = "";

$("#datepicker").datepicker({

    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

        if (!trigger || (previousDate != dateText)) {
            // Do whatever you want to do
            alert("fire!");
            // I decided to alert
            trigger = true;
            previousDate = dateText;
        } else {
            trigger = false; 
        }
    }
});​
```

Try something like this. I had a couple of minutes to test it and it seems to work. Improve on the idea if it doesn't.

I'll explain if you don't understand the awful, ugly idea behind the hack.

Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I used this kind of workaround, event if it's ugly, it's working... But I had to use `setTimeout(function() { trigger = true; }, 1000);`, which is even uglier. If I didn't do that, the method was still triggered twice.

Comment: @Virginie I have modified my answer in order to fix this problem. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 inst.preventDefault();
```

like this:

```
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     onSelect: function(dateText,inst) {       
         alert('s');
         inst.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

EDIT : to remove the calendar after selection of date

a work around is you need to use removeclass:

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

       onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {          
       $(inst.dpDiv).find('.ui-state-highlight.ui-state-hover').removeClass('ui-state-highlight ui-state-hover');          

 },
});
```

Comment: Great, it seems to be the perfect solution! I had the feeling I would have to deal with preventDefault() but didn't know how to handle it. Thanks!

Comment: **UPDATE**: I've been too quick: it's **almost** the perfect solution. No second call BUT the datepicker doesn't hide anymore once the date is selected. Nice try :)

Comment: you need to remove the datepicker once the date is selected, but was your qn is about firing twice or removing the datepicker?

Comment: @Virginie you can add '$.datepicker._hideDatepicker();' before the calling preventDefault(). Remove the alert because it causes to set focus on input field which will show datepicker again. :) Even my answer is also acceptable :)

Comment: My question was about the double firing while keeping the default behaviour of the datepicker, which is to disappear after the date has been selected. The mix between your solution and @SunilChavan 's is the most elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution so far:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        // do stuff
        $.datepicker._hideDatepicker();
        inst.preventDefault();
    }
```

});

`inst.preventDefault()`is the most important part: it prevents the double firing of `onSelect()`. By using it, the datepicker doesn't hide anymore once the date is selected, so you have to call `$.datepicker._hideDatepicker()` to do it.

Thanks to user1042031 and Sunil Chavan.

Comment: I have already updated same answer in my post. Even my answer also explains the root cause of the problem and its fix as well as workaround.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug to me... I've got this tied into all sorts of async calls and it's messing up everything...  best solution I came up with is this:

```
jQuery(".date-picker").each(function (index, item) {
    jQuery(item).removeClass("date-picker");
     item.ondpchange = item.onchange;
    jQuery(item).datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,

    }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
        if (item.ondpchange != null) {
            item.ondpchange();
        }
    });;
    item.onchange = null;


});
```